# Google App Engine API Annotation - Using Environment Variables

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, guice

We are using App Engine and Firebase however we're having a slight issue. We want to use Environment Variables in our API annotations but we've hit a road block.

```
package com.myapp.services;

import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.*;


@Api(
    name = "contacts",
    version = "v1",
    authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
    issuers = {@ApiIssuer(name = "firebase",
            issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/<<PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE>>",
            jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")},
    issuerAudiences = {@ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "<<PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE>>")},
    authLevel = AuthLevel.REQUIRED
)
public class ContactService {

    @ApiMethod(path = "create", httpMethod = "post")
    public Long CreateContact(Contact contact, User user) {
        // Create the record
        return contact.id;
    }
}
```

How do we update the issuer and audiences values on an environment by environment basis? We can use Guice to pass in an environment into the methods however we can't inject into the annotations.

We just want a way to update `<<<PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE>>>` on deployment.

Comment: As far as I know, this is only configureable through the google cloud dashboard when you give your project a name

Comment: There's some articles like this:- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables  
But they don't seem to really show how to use it.